# How to create custom derivatives in CSS/HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've searched from this forum about creating a custom derivatives in the HTML.

What I'm looking for is to create a custom derivatives and should look like this:

```
<div class="color-blue" dismissable/>
<input id="hello" type="text" numeric-only/>
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Vince

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what you mean by "derivatives" in this context but, I think what you need are `data attributes` like `data-numeric-only="true"`. Then you can add whatever logic you need like:

```js
$('[data-dismissable="true"]').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});

$('[data-numeric-only="true"]').keyup(function(){
  $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ""));
});
```

```css
.color-blue{
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-blue" data-dismissable="true"></div>
<input id="hello" type="text" data-numeric-only="true"/>
```

**Or, you could create your own [custom HTML elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)**